# Jquery Regex expression for NOT ALLOWING either only number or Only special character

Tags: jquery, regex

**My text field should have following restriction**

1..Filed should accept combination of alpha numeric  and special Character

2. Field should accept alphabets
3. It should NOT accept only number or Special character.

Please tell me regex expression to fulfill above all condition.

Answer (score 1):

This here would work.

[RegEx Example!](https://regex101.com/r/wrOtVk/2)

```
^(?:(?!^[@$!%*#?&]+$)(?!^[0-9]+$)[A-z0-9@$!%*#?&]+)$
```